# Android Studio : How to save text files from EditText into a specific directory

Tags: android, performance, android-edittext

I am currently making a journal app, so the users type their entry into an EditText and it saves in their phone and they can load it up later. At first I used just getFilesDir() but recently there is this weird rList file that shows up every time I open the app and I couldn't figure it out(I wrote a question about it). So now I want to save these files in this specific directory called TextEntries

Here is the code for my save funcction:

```
 public void save(View v) {
        textFile = inputTitle.getText().toString();
        String text = inputFeelings.getText().toString();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            String rootPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/TextEntries/";
            File root = new File(rootPath);
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            fos = openFileOutput(textFile, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(text.getBytes());
            inputFeelings.getText().clear();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to " + getFilesDir() + "/TextEntries/" + textFile,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All help is welcome and thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, please provide code of `openFileOutput`. I think you dont set `rootPath` to your file

Comment: Hello Anatoli thank you for your comment but can I get some more context. What do you  mean by code of `openFileOutput` because this is all the code I have on it? In regards to the rootpath that is what I am trying to figure out. Thank you once again!

Comment: please only use the android studio tag if you're asking about the IDE specifically, not just because you use it to develop

Comment: @a_local_nobody my apologies

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
openFileOutput(textFile, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with

```
new FileOutputStream(rootPath + textFile)
```

Comment: I tried this today anatoli and it didn't work. It just gave me this error `Attempt to get length of null array`. Hopefully you have an idea on how to solve this issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: when comes this error? By writing or reading? If by writing -> where? If by reading -> please provide the code of your reading file or check if file exists.